# Определить количество групп однородных ячеек таблицы

Tags: java, алгоритм

Программа, которая подсчитывает количество групп смежных ячеек таблицы с одинаковым значением цвета. Смежность определяется по горизонтали или по вертикали. Смежные ячейки помечены одним цветом, который определяет значение ячейки.

Например если заданы цвета:

```
enum Color {
  YELLOW, BLUE, MAGENTA, GREEN, GREY
}
```

и таблица задается значениями

```
Color[][] A = {
    {Color.GREY,    Color.GREEN,   Color.GREEN},
    {Color.GREEN,   Color.MAGENTA, Color.GREEN},
    {Color.MAGENTA, Color.BLUE,    Color.GREEN},
    {Color.BLUE,    Color.BLUE,    Color.BLUE},
    {Color.MAGENTA, Color.MAGENTA, Color.GREEN},
    {Color.YELLOW,  Color.GREEN,   Color.GREEN},
    {Color.GREEN,   Color.YELLOW,  Color.YELLOW}
};
```

то количество однородных груп определяется как 11, что можно посмотреть

```html
<table>
<tbody><tr>
  <td style="width:81.55pt;border:none;padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt" width="109" valign="top">
  <p class="MsoNormal" style="margin-bottom:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;line-height:
  normal"><span lang="EN-US">&nbsp;</span></p>
  </td>
  <td style="width:81.55pt;border:none;border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt;
  padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt" width="109" valign="top">
  <p class="MsoNormal" style="margin-bottom:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;
  text-align:center;line-height:normal" align="center"><span lang="EN-US">0</span></p>
  </td>
  <td style="width:81.55pt;border:none;border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt;
  padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt" width="109" valign="top">
  <p class="MsoNormal" style="margin-bottom:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;
  text-align:center;line-height:normal" align="center"><span lang="EN-US">1</span></p>
  </td>
  <td style="width:81.55pt;border:none;border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt;
  padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt" width="109" valign="top">
  <p class="MsoNormal" style="margin-bottom:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;
  text-align:center;line-height:normal" align="center"><span lang="EN-US">2</span></p>
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td style="width:81.55pt;border:none;border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt;
  padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt" width="109" valign="top">
  <p class="MsoNormal" style="margin-bottom:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;
  text-align:right;line-height:normal" align="right"><span lang="EN-US">0</span></p>
  </td>
  <td style="width:81.55pt;border-top:none;border-left:
  none;border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt;border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt;
  background:#948A54;padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt" width="109" valign="top">
  <p class="MsoNormal" style="margin-bottom:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;
  text-align:center;line-height:normal" align="center"><span lang="EN-US">1</span></p>
  </td>
  <td style="width:81.55pt;border:none;border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt;
  background:#00B050;padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt" width="109" valign="top">
  <p class="MsoNormal" style="margin-bottom:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;line-height:
  normal"><span lang="EN-US">&nbsp;</span></p>
  </td>
  <td style="width:81.55pt;border:none;border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt;
  background:#00B050;padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt" width="109" valign="top">
  <p class="MsoNormal" style="margin-bottom:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;line-height:
  normal"><span lang="EN-US">2</span></p>
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td style="width:81.55pt;border:none;border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt;
  padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt" width="109" valign="top">
  <p class="MsoNormal" style="margin-bottom:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;
  text-align:right;line-height:normal" align="right"><span lang="EN-US">1</span></p>
  </td>
  <td style="width:81.55pt;border-top:none;border-left:
  none;border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt;border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt;
  background:#00B050;padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt" width="109" valign="top">
  <p class="MsoNormal" style="margin-bottom:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;
  text-align:center;line-height:normal" align="center"><span lang="EN-US">3</span></p>
  </td>
  <td style="width:81.55pt;border-top:none;border-left:
  none;border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt;border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt;
  background:#D99594;padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt" width="109" valign="top">
  <p class="MsoNormal" style="margin-bottom:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;
  text-align:center;line-height:normal" align="center"><span lang="EN-US">4</span></p>
  </td>
  <td style="width:81.55pt;border:none;border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt;
  background:#00B050;padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt" width="109" valign="top">
  <p class="MsoNormal" style="margin-bottom:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;line-height:
  normal"><span lang="EN-US">&nbsp;</span></p>
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td style="width:81.55pt;border:none;border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt;
  padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt" width="109" valign="top">
  <p class="MsoNormal" style="margin-bottom:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;
  text-align:right;line-height:normal" align="right"><span lang="EN-US">2</span></p>
  </td>
  <td style="width:81.55pt;border-top:none;border-left:
  none;border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt;border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt;
  background:#D99594;padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt" width="109" valign="top">
  <p class="MsoNormal" style="margin-bottom:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;
  text-align:center;line-height:normal" align="center"><span lang="EN-US">5</span></p>
  </td>
  <td style="width:81.55pt;border:none;border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt;
  background:#548DD4;padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt" width="109" valign="top">
  <p class="MsoNormal" style="margin-bottom:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;line-height:
  normal"><span lang="EN-US">&nbsp;</span></p>
  </td>
  <td style="width:81.55pt;border-top:none;border-left:
  none;border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt;border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt;
  background:#00B050;padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt" width="109" valign="top">
  <p class="MsoNormal" style="margin-bottom:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;line-height:
  normal"><span lang="EN-US">&nbsp;</span></p>
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td style="width:81.55pt;border:none;border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt;
  padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt" width="109" valign="top">
  <p class="MsoNormal" style="margin-bottom:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;
  text-align:right;line-height:normal" align="right"><span lang="EN-US">3</span></p>
  </td>
  <td colspan="3" style="width:244.65pt;border:none;
  border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:#548DD4;padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt" width="326" valign="top">
  <p class="MsoNormal" style="margin-bottom:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;
  text-align:center;line-height:normal" align="center"><span lang="EN-US">6</span></p>
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td style="width:81.55pt;border:none;border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt;
  padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt" width="109" valign="top">
  <p class="MsoNormal" style="margin-bottom:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;
  text-align:right;line-height:normal" align="right"><span lang="EN-US">4</span></p>
  </td>
  <td colspan="2" style="width:163.1pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;
  border-left:none;background:#D99594;padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt" width="217" valign="top">
  <p class="MsoNormal" style="margin-bottom:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;
  text-align:center;line-height:normal" align="center"><span lang="EN-US">7</span></p>
  </td>
  <td style="width:81.55pt;border-top:solid windowtext 1.0pt;
  border-left:none;border-bottom:none;border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt;
  background:#00B050;padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt" width="109" valign="top">
  <p class="MsoNormal" style="margin-bottom:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;line-height:
  normal"><span lang="EN-US">&nbsp;</span></p>
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td style="width:81.55pt;border:none;border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt;
  padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt" width="109" valign="top">
  <p class="MsoNormal" style="margin-bottom:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;
  text-align:right;line-height:normal" align="right"><span lang="EN-US">5</span></p>
  </td>
  <td style="width:81.55pt;border-top:none;border-left:
  none;border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt;border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt;
  background:#F79646;padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt" width="109" valign="top">
  <p class="MsoNormal" style="margin-bottom:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;line-height:
  normal"><span lang="EN-US">8</span></p>
  </td>
  <td colspan="2" style="width:163.1pt;border-top:none;
  border-left:none;border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt;border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt;
  background:#00B050;padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt" width="217" valign="top">
  <p class="MsoNormal" style="margin-bottom:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;
  text-align:center;line-height:normal" align="center"><span lang="EN-US">9</span></p>
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td style="width:81.55pt;border:none;border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt;
  padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt" width="109" valign="top">
  <p class="MsoNormal" style="margin-bottom:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;
  text-align:right;line-height:normal" align="right"><span lang="EN-US">6</span></p>
  </td>
  <td style="width:81.55pt;border-top:none;border-left:
  none;border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt;border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt;
  background:#00B050;padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt" width="109" valign="top">
  <p class="MsoNormal" style="margin-bottom:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;line-height:
  normal"><span lang="EN-US">10</span></p>
  </td>
  <td colspan="2" style="width:163.1pt;border-top:none;
  border-left:none;border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt;border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt;
  background:#F79646;padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt" width="217" valign="top">
  <p class="MsoNormal" style="margin-bottom:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;
  text-align:center;line-height:normal" align="center"><span lang="EN-US">11</span></p>
  </td>
 </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я пробовал написать функцию, которая должна возвращать колличество груп

```
Color[][] S;

public int function(Color[][] A) {
  int N = A.length;
  int M = A[N-1].length;
  S = new Color[N][M];
  int cnt = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < M; j++) {
      System.out.println("A["+i+"]["+j+"]=" +A[i][j]);
      int c = A[i][j].ordinal();
      if (S[i][j] == null) {
        S[i][j] = Color.values()[c];
        cnt++;
      }

      //влево
      int l = j - 1;
      if (l >= 0 ) {
        if (A[i][l] == Color.values()[c]) {
          S[i][l] = S[i][j];
        }
      }
      //вправо
      l = j + 1;
      if (l < M ) {
        if (A[i][l] == Color.values()[c]) {
          S[i][l] = S[i][j];
        }
      }
      //вверх
      int k = i - 1;
      if (k >= 0) {
        if (A[k][j] == Color.values()[c]) {
          S[k][j] = S[i][j];
        }
      }
      //вниз
      k = i + 1;
      if (k < N) {
        if (A[k][j] == Color.values()[c]) {
          S[k][j] = S[i][j];
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return cnt;
}
```

Эта функция работает неправильно, потому что возвращает 13. В чем ошибка и как ее можно понять и исправить?

Comment: Группа 6 - элемент [2,1] инициализируется новым значением, счетчик групп увеличивается и из соседних элементов с тем же цветом инициализируется  элемент [3,1]. Через  итерацию элемент [3,0] классифицируется как новая группа. Та же беда с группой 9.

Comment: @Sedov Почему так происходит? Как это можно изменить?

Comment: обход массива, к каждой пустой ячейке применить волновой алгоритм заполнения например.

Comment: @Serodv я не совсем понимаю, что значит волновой алгоритм заполнения? Разве я использую не волновой?

Comment: нет. алгоритм должен всю группу обозначить, а у вас только соседние ячейки.

Comment: @Serodv Мне кажется, что это слишком усложняет, т.к. количество направлений увеличивается с геометрической прогрессией и надо помечать как-то ячейки в которых уже побывал, чтобы не было зацикливаний.

Answer (score 1):

Алгоритм поиска связанных групп элементов можно реализовать следующим образом:
- сгрузить все элементы в виде объектов (x,y,цвет) в любую коллекцию A
- вынуть любой элемент и переложить в коллекцию B
- пройтись по одноцветным с ним элементам коллекции A и проверить, не являются ли они соседями переложенного ранее элемента (сравнивать координаты), если да - их тоже переложить в коллекцию B
- повторять для каждого элемента коллекции B подобный обход по А, пока мы не вынем из А все элементы связной одноцветной фигуры (т.е. в результате обхода в В не появится новых элемнтов)
т.о. в коллекции В у нас появится фигура любой формы и размера, отвечающая условиям поиска
- дальше мы можем куда то сохранить найденную фигуру или просто инкрементировать счетчик и повторить все начиная со второго пункта пока не разберем коллекцию А на отдельные фигуры.

Comment: Куда выложить? Куда пройтись? Я тут чуть не начал писать обход по дереву, но по том передумал.

Comment: Дерево тут без надобности. Просто последовательно перекладываем из одной коллекции в другую элементы, которые удовлетворяют условию "этот элемент является соседним и цвет совпадает".  Как только они заканчиваются - значит мы нашли всю область, удовлетворяющую условию. Не нужно даже работать с ними как с матрицей. Вполне достаточно списка.

Comment: Ну да, у соседнего элемента есть соседний и т.д. без конца.

Answer (score 1):

Реализация простейшего волнового алгоритма применительно к вашей задаче. При желании рекурсия заменяется итерацией. Также не составит труда добавить функционал, определяющий множества точек групп.

```
class FoundGroups {
    private Color[][] colors;
    private Color[][] tmp;
    int rowCount, colCount;

    public FoundGroups(Color[][] colors) {
        this.colors = colors;
        rowCount = colors.length;
        colCount = colors[0].length;
        tmp = new Color[rowCount][colCount];
    }

    public int getGroupsCount() {
        int cnt = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < colCount; j++) {
                if (tmp[i][j] == null) {
                    cnt++;
                    fillCell(i, j, colors[i][j].ordinal());
                }
            }
        }
        return cnt;
    }

    private void fillCell(int row, int col, int color) {
        if (row < 0 || row > rowCount - 1 || col < 0 || col > colCount - 1) return;
        if (tmp[row][col] != null || colors[row][col] != Color.values()[color]) return;
        tmp[row][col] = Color.values()[color];
        fillCell(row-1,col,color);
        fillCell(row+1,col,color);
        fillCell(row,col-1,color);
        fillCell(row,col+1,color);
    }
}
```